# Ubuntu 14 intermittently can't come out of hibernation / sleep mode

Tags: 14.04, hibernate, screensaver

Sometimes when my Ubuntu 14 goes into hibernation mode then pressing a key won't bring it back. What could be wrong? Now I must make a hard powercycling to get back to my desktop if the screensaver starts. What is wrong and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernation mode isn't the same as sleep mode. Hibernation actually turns the computer off, meaning you need to press the power button to wake it up. For sleep, it's possible that your computer isn't designed to wake up by key-press. Try pressing the power button to wake it up instead.